# Problems loading COM object with win32com in python

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to communicate with an application (Digital Micrograph) through a COM object. This works in LabView, and I am now trying to do the same thing in python with win32com. I am getting a range of errors depending on how I implement this in win32com that don't really make sense.

If I follow the [quick start guide](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) and try to use `win32com.client.Dispatch()`, the object I get has no methods or classes except the defaults from win32com, although I know that the module generated by makepy has methods.

```
import win32com.client
sendDMscript = win32com.client.Dispatch('COMExamplePlugIn.COMExampleInterface')
dir(sendDMscript)
```

returns only

```
['_ApplyTypes_',
 '_FlagAsMethod',
 '_LazyAddAttr_',
 '_NewEnum',
 '_Release_',
 '__AttrToID__',
 '__LazyMap__',
 '__bool__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__int__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_builtMethods_',
 '_enum_',
 '_find_dispatch_type_',
 '_get_good_object_',
 '_get_good_single_object_',
 '_lazydata_',
 '_make_method_',
 '_mapCachedItems_',
 '_oleobj_',
 '_olerepr_',
 '_print_details_',
 '_proc_',
 '_unicode_to_string_',
 '_username_',
 '_wrap_dispatch_']
```

If I instead use gencache, the class that I want exists, but I get an error when I try to create an instance of it.

```
import win32com.client
sendDMscript_method = win32com.client.gencache.GetModuleForProgID('COMExamplePlugIn.COMExampleInterface').ICOMExampleInterface
instance = sendDMscript_method()
```

This returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-55d05602784d> in <module>
----> 1 instance = sendDMscript()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py in __init__(self, oobj)
    429         def __init__(self, oobj=None):
    430                 if oobj is None:
--> 431                         oobj = pythoncom.new(self.CLSID)
    432                 elif isinstance(oobj, DispatchBaseClass):
    433                         try:

com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

I've tried to trick my way around this bug by passing the right oobj as an argument to `sendDMscript_method()`, and that allows me to create an instance of the class, but ultimately also fails when I try to run one of the methods in the class:

```
import win32com.client
from pywintypes import IID
sendDMscript_method = win32com.client.gencache.GetModuleForProgID('COMExamplePlugIn.COMExampleInterface').ICOMExampleInterface
CLSID = IID('{8C0B6A41-4ED2-4B44-B7B1-6492695B9C3D}')
instance = sendDMscript_method(CLSID)
instance.ExecuteScript(script='result("I did it")')
```

This results in the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8fdc545bf83d> in <module>
----> 1 instance.ExecuteScript(script='result("I did it")')

C:\Users\VALUED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\8C0B6A41-4ED2-4B44-B7B1-6492695B9C3Dx0x2x0.py in ExecuteScript(self, script)
     57         def ExecuteScript(self, script=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
     58                 'method ExecuteScript'
---> 59         return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1, LCID, 1, (5, 0), ((8, 1),),script
     60             )
     61 

AttributeError: 'PyIID' object has no attribute 'InvokeTypes'
```

When I googled these bugs, I saw people talking about 32 bit-64 bit problems. I am running 32-bit Windows 7 with 32-bit python 3.7 in Anaconda, using pywin32 installed via Anaconda. I also tested the quick start guide's approach with 32-bit python 3.7 installed from python.org and pywin32 installed via pip and got the same first error. The application I am trying to communicate with is also 32-bit. Anybody know what's going wrong?